# Deny access to certain pages based on date

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to deny access to certain pages using `.htaccess` based on current date?

Here's the deal. I've implemented April Fool's system to my sites (it basically displays some funny page that is designed to fool visitors something just happened - anything bad - every April 1st, and after reloading page it displays the actual site - using session id).

I want to let visitors view past April Fool's pages using a custom dirlist index page that do not list pages that are upcoming (clearly, if it is supposed to be a surprise). But I want to lock the upcoming pages so the visitors can't display upcoming pages using direct access (manually typing their address in browser address bar).

Pages are named using a naming schematic of `year.php` (so every year has its own fool page). Each of that page displays in a specific date - it's April 1st of that year. I want to deny access to those pages that didn't pass the current April Fool's season. So namely it's 2018. I've prepared an April Fool's page for 2019 (named `2019.php`). If visitor enters the address `example.com/april_fools_dir/2019.php`, it should show him `Access Denied` error, until it's April 1st 2019. Don't want to implement it in each page separately, and also do not want to have each that page rely on an included portion implementing this feature. I'd like to avoid having to implement this in PHP if it's possible to use that in `.htaccess`. I can figure out PHP implementation myself, but I'd like to avoid that...

Why do I need such feature as deny certain pages until a specific date? It's a strategic move. I don't want to have the upcoming April Fool's pages spoiled by exclusively investigative visitors that try to access the pages that are not yet listed in the history page. It will simply throw an `Access Denied` error and that page will get public after April Fool's of that particular year passed.

Comment: Looks like there's no will. Nevermind, I've got to write few lines of code in PHP and it works, ready to deploy.

Comment: It's certainly possible to do using mod_rewrite. But generally speaking, this sites prefers that you show some basic effort to solve the problem yourself before asking.

Comment: @JennyD That's a little bit of problem. I couldn't figure out how to do it, even didn't know if it is even possible, and Google didn't help at all. So I asked. It's okay, already did it using PHP trickery, just few lines of code to add...

Comment: You can delete this one. Just for clarifying, how could I make it using htaccess way? Because I know literally no way to do it, nor could I figure it out myself at all.

Comment: So few years later, I was able to fine tune wording and simplify my search query, now I found this tutorial: https://harrybailey.com/2015/08/htaccess-redirects-based-on-date-and-time/comment-page-1/ This is exactly what I needed! I also found out that ServerFault is aimed for professional server admins, I am not a professional, I just own a personal website that is hosted somewhere, it's a place I can show my creations from, and my personal blog. Nothing too serious. I also wanted to include some April Fools joke, which I then abandoned. I want to revive them however, for an upcoming redesign.

Comment: Although, it does specify redirects, denying access is something else. A viable workaround would be to redirect pages in upcoming April Fools jokes to a page that tells the visitor they don't quite have permission to access that yet. I guess I'm going to stick with that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the PHP way to do it. I simply call this function giving it the specific year:

```
function deny_access($year) {
    $current_date = [
        'day' => date("d"),
        'month' => date("m"),
        'year' => date("Y")
    ];

    if($current_date['month'] < 4) {
        if($current_date['year'] <= $year) {
            header('403 Forbidden', true, 403);
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        if($current_date['year'] < $year) {
            header('403 Forbidden', true, 403);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

This function is then included and called in each fool page. The result is `403 Forbidden` HTTP request, so exactly what I expected. After importing it in my websites the response is `500 Internal Server Error` (maybe because it can't handle PHP forced `403 Forbidden` response), but that's okay, it actually makes it even better than expected...

EDIT: I forgot to say that fiddling with the given year changes the HTTP response. I wanted to try out how the server will response if the April Fool's page was set to already passed (lowering the year), and the page displays fully working. So the only thing that gives an originally unexpected `500 Internal Server Error` response is the `deny_access($year)` function that met the conditions for `403 Forbidden` HTTP response call. So nothing I should worry about, it works as expected = denies access before it's ready to show.